# How to make a ajax loading component by using angularjs service?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I want to make a specific component for showing loading icon when the browser waits to load data from json. Is there any possible way to do it by using a service ??
html :

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title> ERP </title>

</head>

<body >

    <div ng-controller="data"><span class="loading" ng-show="loader"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></span>
        <table>
            <tr><td>{{data1}}</td><td>{{data1}}</td><td>{{data1}}</td></tr>
</table>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ctrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js :

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('data', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.loader = null ;
  if($scope.loader == null )
  {
    $scope.loader = true ;
  }
      $http.get('events.json').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.loader = false ;
      console.log(data);
      $scope.data1 = data ;
      console.log($scope.data1);

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
}]);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your implementation? And also, please use proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the original `$http` to provide a `customizedHttp` service. in this service, provide the same interface with `$http`. when sending `GET` request to the server, the `customizedHttp` broadcast an event to show the loading flag. and after receiving response, broadcast another event to hide the loading flag.

to control the flag, you'd better to write a directive.